# Ошибка в многофайловом проекте

Tags: c++, объявление

```
//Header.h
#pragma one
int arr[3];
void print();

//Header.cpp
#include "Header.h"
#include <iostream>
void print()
{
std::cout << arr[0];
}

//Source.cpp (главный файл)
#include "Header.h"
int main()
{
    arr[0] = 3;
    return 0;
}
```

В результате:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А когда в файле Header.h

```
int arr[3];
```

меняю на

```
extern int arr[3];
```

Вылетает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `#pragma once` пишется

Comment: `#pragma once` и любой другой header guard гарантирует вам лишь то, что библиотека подключится единожды конкретно в один файл, не в программу в целом. В первый раз у вас выскакивает ошибка потому, что один и тот же идентификатор определён два раза(в Header.cpp и в Source.cpp). Во второй раз потому что вы в каждый файл всего лишь ввели идентификатор, а когда вы его используете он нигде не определён. Советую вам прочитать про уровни линковки.

Comment: @MatveyKiselyov Так и гуглить "уровни линковки"? Чёт не то выдаёт

Comment: @zhukov Тогда просто забейте ключевые слова `extern` и `static`.

Answer (score 4):

Добавьте к

```
extern int arr[3];
```

в заголовочном файле

```
int arr[3];
```

в **одном** .cpp-файле.

Кстати, правильно не

```
#pragma one
```

а

```
#pragma once
```

Comment: Если в _Header.h_ `extern int arr[3];`, а в _Header.cpp_ `int arr[3]; `, то где фактически объявляется массив arr?

Comment: @zhukov Там, где вы его объявите) Ключевое слово extern для переменных это как forward declarations для функций.

Comment: @MatveyKiselyov ну в данном случае где объявится?

Comment: Объявлен в заголовке, определен в .cpp. *"По-моему, так" (с) Пух"* Строгие гуру в стандарте могу иметь иное мнение, основанное на linkage, но для практических целей, мне кажется, такого представления достаточно.